# css - Make two <section> tags side by side

Tags: html, css, sections

My current code is this:

```
<section><iframe id="frame1" width="675" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></section>
<section><textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea></section>
```

My assignment requires me to use the section tag on both the iframe and the textarea, but I need them to line up side by side. When I take they section tags away, they line up perfectly, but I need to keep the section tags. How do I get this to line up like 2 columns but still keep the tags?

Comment: Not enough information. Is that the only content of your page (aka is your structure `body > section + section`)?

Comment: You need CSS to line them up. HTML alone wont do it with the code you submitted.

Comment: My code is too long to post...but let me post a little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CSS styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) with [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and look at [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Quick and dirty fix:

```
<section style="float:left; width:675px;"><iframe id="frame1" width="675" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></section>
<section style="float:left; width:200px;"><textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea></section>
```

Comment: +1, Quick and dirty is right :) Please don't use inline CSS whenever possible, especially since you are just learning -- it's too easy to create bad habits in the name of 'getting it to work'

Comment: I put the width in the section tags, but I moved the style up to my css section and we are good to go. Thank you!

Comment: True.. but from the current version of the question it's *impossible* to give an exact best practice answer. Will update to point in the right direction.

Comment: Why there may be a better option than floats: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: I went with this but I put the style in my css. Thanks for the quick and easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

```
<section style="display:block;float:left; width:675px;">
     <iframe id="frame1" width="675" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
<section style="display:block;float:left; width:200px;">
     <textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to lean away from floats and towards inline-block

HTML

```
<section class="left">
   <iframe id="frame1" width="675" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    
 </section>
 <section class="right">
    <textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea>    
 </section>
```

CSS

```
.left
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:675px;
}


.right
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nV8ag/

Inline-block does have a few caveats though: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 0):

You should always put styles in an external stylesheet.

Then you could place this code into your HTML:

```
<section id="section-1"><iframe width="675" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></section>
<section id="section-2"><textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea></section>
```

And have something like this in your CSS file:

```
section {display:-moz-inline-stack;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;zoom:1;*display:inline;}
#section-1 {width:680px; height:400px;} These are the ID's of your sections
#section-2 {width:200px; height:480px;}
```

Also if you are learning to use HTML5 elements you should make sure that you include the HTML5 shiv for older browsers.

Just pop this into the head tags of the HTML document.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set width of both sections and set float left for both as:

```
<section style="float:left; width:675px;"><iframe id="frame1" width="675" height="380"           src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hmAFhsxWhdY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></section>
<section style="float:left; width:200px;"><textarea rows="24" cols="25" id="desc" width="200" height="478">Text here</textarea></section>
```